# Is this a correct way to write the summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have values such as 2,4, 7, 10 , that is not sequential but are stored in array w. Can I use the summation 
$$ {\sum_{i = 1}^{n} w[i]} $$

or there is another way to write it down ?

Comment: That is OK.  Perhaps mathematicians would often prefer $$\sum_{i=1}^n w_i$$ instead of the brackets.

Comment: As long as you define the notation $w[i]$, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in programming if we have array $w={1,2,3,4....}$,then we write $w[i]$,in mathematics you can simple write $w_i$

Answer (score 0):

This notation is not considered unusual in computer science. While I don't have an example for the sum over an array handy, the bracket notation occurs, e.g., in Bradley and Manna's "The Calculus of Computation".